# MockWebserver and Retrofit 2.0

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, retrofit2

Trying to unit test a `Retrofit 2.0` response using `MockWebServer`. I have the webserver setup, but the problem occurs when i am trying to pass a mock `json` file as a response. To illustrate, my folder structure is:

```
src->test->java->package_name->class_name.java

src->test->resources->list_success.json
```

My unit test:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    server = new MockWebServer();
    serviceHelper = new ServiceHelper();

}
@Test
public void testEventBusIdPostedOnSuccessfulServiceCall() throws Exception {
    server.start();
    server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody(getStringFromFile(RuntimeEnvironment.application, "list_success.json")));
    MainActivity.URL = server.url("/").toString();

    serviceHelper.getIndividualData("Store","7");
    verify(eventBus).post(any());
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception{
    server.shutdown();
}
```

Everything works fine. The retrofit call which is async is triggered with the mock JSON. However, the callback never gets triggered. I tried putting in a countdown latch within the actual service implementation, but nothing happens either.

```
    public void getIndividualData(String item, String number) {

            Call<DataList> dataList = RestClient.get().getList(item, number);
            dataList.enqueue(new Callback<DataList>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<DataList> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    /*data persistence should take place before sending out the eventbus message.
                     Passing the response object directly for sample purpose. */
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new IndividualItemEvent(response.body().Values));
                //    latch.countDown(); ---->might be needed for retrofit async unit testing
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("%%%%%", "retrofit failure");
                   // latch.countDown(); ---->might be needed for retrofit async unit testing
                }
            });
//        try {
//            latch.await();
//        } catch (InterruptedException e) { ---->might be needed for retrofit async unit testing
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
```

Am i missing something here?
Thanks.

Comment: "sends out an Otto Bus event message" -- AFAIK, that's not going to work, unless you're going to mock all that too. Otto requires Android; in particular, that may be the source of your `getMainLooper()` error.

Comment: The bigger issue is more of how to test retrofit with mockwebserver whilst having a static JSON file. The otto bus error ended up as a byproduct while trying to work around the static JSON issue, which i can ignore.

Comment: "The bigger issue is more of how to test retrofit with mockwebserver whilst having a static JSON file" -- beats me. I use instrumentation testing, eschewing local unit testing. Sorry!

Comment: How are you running this test? On your computer, emulator, or a real android device?